# Logo de carga cuando un archivo se termine de descargar

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una duda, estoy en un proyecto en MVC .NET que consiste en una pagina web que esta local de momento, en el que el usuario llena un formulario con unos determinados datos en el apartado de vista, y hasta abajo hay un boton de envio, cuando envias el formulario, en la parte del controlador, los datos que el usuario ingresó en los inputs se pasan a una plantilla de word y llena esa plantilla, despues lo descarga en PDF a la computadora.

Pero quiero que en lo que dura todo ese proceso, se muestre un logo de carga para indicar que aun se sigue procesando el PDF, pero cuando se termina de descargar el documento, el logo nunca desaparece.

Saben si hay alguna manera de detectar cuando la descarga haya finalizado? Todo el tema del logo de carga lo estoy manejando con javascript y con setTimeOut, pero no quiero que sea por medio de temporizadores, quiero que sea en automatico en cuanto se temrine la descarga, el logo desaparezca y borre el contenido de los inputs.

Este es el script para el logo y el mensaje de carga.

Gracias.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("AssignationLetter").addEventListener("submit", function () {
        // Mostrar círculo de carga y ocultar botón

        document.getElementById("loading-container").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("generateBtn").style.display = "none";

    });

    document.getElementById("AssignationLetter").addEventListener("submit", function () {
       

        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById("AssignationLetter").reset();
        }, 14000); //Se borran los inputs a los 14 segundos


        setTimeout(function () {

            // Ocultar el contenedor de carga y mostrar el mensaje de éxito
            document.getElementById("loading-container").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("mensaje").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("generateBtn").style.display = "block"; 

            // Ocultar el mensaje después de unos segundos
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("mensaje").style.display = "none";
            }, 3000); // Ocultar mensaje después de 3 segundos
        }, 16000); //Lo que tarda en enviar los datos

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Usar setTimeout con tiempos hardcodeados es una chapuza, y si la red tarda más, o menos? No está bien, nada bien. En vez de eso haz la llamada con fetch directamente, de esa manera sabrás exactamente cuando ha terminado. Tienes mil ejemplos en google e incluso aquí mismo en SOes

Comment: Estas usando ajax???